# Correctly Aligning Images with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in the process of creating a HTML/CSS layout for a Kiosk-style site.

However, I am having a few issues making the alignment of the images and text to work exactly how I want.

The logo and header should be fixed in the same place across every page, whereas I might need to expand the amount of buttons on-screen.

Here is the illustration of an example: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuEj6.jpg), where:

- Black box represents logo
- Blue boxes represent individual buttons

Current HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<html>
<body background="background.png"> 

<div id="logo">
    <img src="logo.png">
</div>

<br>

<div id="icons1">
    <img src="button-wmcweb.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="icons1">
    <img src="button-appointments.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="icons1">
    <img src="button-prescriptions.png"></a>
</div>

<br>

<div id="icons2">
    <img src="button-somccg.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="icons2">
    <img src="button-patient.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="icons2">
    <img src="button-nhschoices.png"></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
text-align:center;
}

#mainContainer {
margin:0 auto;
} 

#icons1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#icons2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Is using inline blocks the best practice for what I'm trying to achieve?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your HTML is very incorrect... you should run that through a validator to help you identify structural issues first before worrying about how it looks. `<link>` should be in the document head, `<img>` & `<br>` tags need to be closed if you're using XHTML, you have `</a>` but there are no opening anchor tags in the first place, there can only be a single `id` per page, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have created for you a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danek/CtZL9/) with what you want as a starting point.

[Click for the full screen mode for the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/danek/CtZL9/embedded/result/)

There is the full code below for the ease of referencing.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body background="background.png">
        <div id="logo">
            <div id="logoimg">
                <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926650/93b6/n9S5OGKt8L0.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div id="logotext">lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="row"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <img src="http://cs614926.vk.me/v614926744/752f/eY60jo6aYo4.jpg" />
            </a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`style.css`:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#logoimg, #logotext, .row > img {
    display: inline;
}
#logo, .row {
    margin: 30px 10px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
#logotext {
    min-width: 320px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
img {
    width: 320px;
    resize: noresize;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

For more info on HTML/CSS, consider checking the following [w3school tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/): [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Comment: Definitely have to up vote this for simple fact that you answered the question to completeness with example and wasn't a D-Bag about it though it may have be trivial in nature before you said by the way go do a little reading.

Comment: Many Thanks for your response, extremely helpful. Got the pages up and working and looks great. Just what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @user3429299, I would be very grateful if you consider choosing my answer, it it heps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML was wrong in a few places. No opening `<a>` tag, multiple `id's` with the same name, and the `<link>` for the css needs to be inside the `<head></head>` tags, as shown below.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Is this what you're looking to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8gVL/